# SQL: Get data between the current date and current date +15 days

Tags: mysql

In My application have to find upcoming birthday members , so I have to find the birthday between current date and current date +15 days.

I tried this query

```
Select name from tname 
where dayofyear(birthday)-dayofyear(now()) between 0 and 15
```

this query is not working when the current date reaches end of year

Please provide me the correct way.

Comment: In Table, birthday- 1986/12/25 like date , so we have to consider only month and date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from tname 
where DATEDIFF(MAKEDATE(YEAR(now()),DAYOFYEAR(birthday)),now()) BETWEEN 0 and 15
```

this may help you..,this will the short method.

Comment: For OP and the poster of the answer information: you **both** should consider performance implications of your SQL. You are calling **6** different functions for **EVERY** row in your table to get your result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  tname
WHERE
  birthday + INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birthday) YEAR
    BETWEEN (CURDATE()) AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 DAY;
```